# Javascript shif left or right bidirectional

Tags: javascript, shift

Thanks to this great site using excellent code from Nope i get this code:

```
var myStringArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"];

var loopByX = function(x){
  var y = myStringArray.splice(0,x);
  myStringArray = myStringArray.concat(y);

  return y;
}

console.log(loopByX(3));
console.log(loopByX(3));
console.log(loopByX(3));
console.log(loopByX(3));
console.log(loopByX(3));
```

That works great...i added it to HTML5 application and see that i have a little wrong describe example of output so i need to get this output:

```
1
2
3

2
3
4

3
4
5

4
5
6

5
6
7

6
7
8

7
8
9

8
9
10

9
10
1

10
1
2

1
2
3
```

so to get value minus one or plus one (pressing up or down buttons so it is called bidirection) using above code i get 3 items up or down and it works..but i see when i copy paste the code i need to get one item up or down in loop...if can be done to modify code to do that...i try to do x-1 in function and y-1 but it is not going to give me above example output...

So i need function that i can call loopByX(3) and multiple calling function it will be shifting left by one place in loop and calling multiple function loopByX(-3) shifting right by one place in loop...what needs to be modified to archieve above output?

Many Thanks.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted output after clicking.

Comment: example is above...i defined array as var myStringArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]; and output is 123 234 345 etc..please see above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the double array and the adjusted index.

```js
function take(direction) {
    index += direction + array.length;
    index %= array.length;
    console.log(array.concat(array).slice(index, index + 3).join(' '));
}

var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    index = 0;
```

```html
<button onclick="take(-1)">-</button>
<button onclick="take(1)">+</button>
```

With `<div> ... </div>`

```js
function take(direction) {
    index += direction + array.length;
    index %= array.length;
    console.log(
        array
            .concat(array)
            .slice(index, index + 3)
            .map(v => `<div>${ v }</div>`)
            .join('')
    );
}

var array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    index = 0;
```

```html
<button onclick="take(-1)">-</button>
<button onclick="take(1)">+</button>
```

Comment: How can be done to add to eache number <div> and </div>? For example <div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>? Output is excellent need only to add div tags and then all will be function perfectly

Comment: Thanks..now app works perfect and really fast..you save me many hours of searching and testing for code...i vote for your answer and is superb fast and working perfectly..thank you nina